# Validate String With Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to validate a string with this regex

```
var regexAgencia = new Regex("^(?!0000)([0-9]{4})");
var result = regexAgencia.IsMatch(agencia);
```

Valid Options:

```
N-X
NN-X
NNN-X
NNNN-X
N
NN 
NNN 
NNNN
```

Invalid Options:

```
0-X 
00-X 
000-X 
0000-X
0
00
000
0000
```

Where N is any number 0-9 and X can be X or 0-9

When I validade this "014777417" the regex return true

I need help to write a regex to validade this string with this rules.

Comment: You need to describe your problem more detailed, I realy don't know why do you think `014777417` shouldn't match regexp `^(?!0000)([0-9]{4})` which mean: 
if( begins with not "0000" and have 4 digits )

Comment: What is the question? Why are these options invalid? Is it leading zeros?

Comment: what is N and what is X in your rule? Does `-` should be in text or it's just to visualise?

Comment: N is any number between 0 and 9 and X can be X or any number between 0 and 9

Comment: this 014777417 is a invalid option

Comment: No, 0000 is not valid

Comment: is 1101 valid?  So, it is just all zeroes that's not valid, or is any zero invalid?  Maybe in your example if you replace N with actual numbers that work (including ones with zero, if relevant), that will help us visualize.

Comment: 1101 is valid. Only all zeroes that´s not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
^(?=\d*[1-9])\d{1,4}(?:-[X\d])?$
```

It starts with a positive look ahead to ensure a digit other than zero is present (`(?=\d*[1-9])`). Thereafter it matches 1-4 digits, optionally followed by a hyphen and a digit or `X`.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sakttr/2).

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can do this through just Regex, however, I always have this lingering fear of creating code that either:

1) only I understand or remember
2) even I don't understand when looking back

In that spirit, it seems if you do a simple split, your string might be easier to evaluate:

```
string[] parts = agencia.Split('-');
if ((parts.Length == 1 && Regex.IsMatch(agencia, @"^\d{1,4}$")) ||
    (parts.Length == 2 && Regex.IsMatch(parts[0], @"^\d{1,4}$")) && 
        Regex.IsMatch(parts[1], @"^[0-9X]$"))
{

}
```

-- EDIT --

I can't tell if you want 0 or not, so if you don't, change `\d` from to `[1-9]`.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to have two tests: one to check if it could be valid, followed by one to exclude the special case of all leading zeros being invalid:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] agencias = { "", "1234-5", "0-9", "014777417", "0000", "1-23", "01-0", "1-234 abcd", "0123-4" };

    var regexAgenciaValid = new Regex("^(([0-9]{1,4})(-[0-9])?)$");
    var regexAgenciaInvalid = new Regex("^((0{1,4})(-[0-9])?)$");

    foreach (string agencia in agencias)
    {
        var result = regexAgenciaValid.IsMatch(agencia) && !regexAgenciaInvalid.IsMatch(agencia);
        Console.WriteLine(agencia + " " + result);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Output:

```
 False
1234-5 True
0-9 False
014777417 False
0000 False
1-23 False
01-0 True
1-234 abcd False
0123-4 True
```

This has the bonus of being easier to modify in the future.